# Display the name of current user in the horizontal menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using `Asp.Net/C#`.I am using `Asp.Net's` built-in `Membership Framework`.I have a requirement wherein the current(logged-in) user's name should be displayed in the horizontal menu towards the right side.The `aspnet_Users` table stores the UserName in the form of some code like `ppp001` where as the actual name of the user `For Example: John Smith` is stored in the table which is linked to `aspnet_Users` table using a `Foreign Key constraint`.So my question is how do I display  the users name from that table to my menu.Should I use `repeater` control.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: if you are going to display single user(logged in), then there is no point using repeater control.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , so how do I do that , any other work around.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma , any other alternative.

Comment: @freebird: just access the LinkButton/Label from the Menu and assign the value.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma do you mean that I should assign the value to Label and then display the Label's value in the menu , am I correct ?

Comment: @freebird:of course. don't display anything until user login.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma what I did earlier was I stored the name of the user in a global variable after authorization , but the problem was sometimes when the page is posted frequently , the Global variable gets empty.

Comment: use session variable instead. Session["LoggedInUser"]= user; because keeping username in session variable is the best approach.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma I am using Session for my cause , but will I have to take care of timeout and all.I have not used session variables before.

Comment: Session is nothing just session variable, you keep the value which stores on the server side. if you are already using this then I recommend you to hold username to the session. you should not store the larger value to the session. and don't worry about timeout, that is how session works.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma I just used session variable to hold my users name , initially it showed properly , but after few mins or so , it was showing empty.

Comment: @freebird: go through this link for detail:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to store the first name and last name in the profile provider and then use a label or div which has runat="sever"

in the web.config

```
<profile enabled="true">
    <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="string"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="string"/>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

then set your div or label

```
   FirstName.Text = Profile.FirstName;
   LastName.Text = Profile.LastName;
```

The disadvantage with using the profile provider is that all the profile properties get concatenated into a big string so it's hard to query against that.  The better way to do this is to create your own BasePage class which makes a call to the database to retrieve the first name and last name from a specific table, using the foreign key like you mentioned.  I usually set this to a MyLoggedInUser property of the page.  That way all your pages can get to it via this.Page.MyLoggedInUser.FirstName, etc..